# How to use a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a question / problem about a variable.

I have two page, in the first one I recover data and in the second one I do some operations.

ActivityPage.js (the first one)

```
recoverActivity() {
  // this function check every second if the size of array > 1000
  // this call only a function in the other page (Operations)
  Operations.write({
    arrayTimestamp: this.arrayTimestamp,
    // other things
  });
}

//this function when the user click a stop button.
stopActivity() {
  Actions.Operations({
    arrayTimestamp: this.arrayTimestamp,
  });
}
```

And the I have another page

Operations.js:

```
//this is called from the first page directly
write(objectData) {
  //...
  this.timestampCheck(objectData.arrayTimestamp);
  //...
}

//this is call from the ComponentDidMount of the second page.
stopClick() {
  //...
  this.timestampCheck(this.props.arrayTimestamp);
  //...
}
```

Now my problem is in this timestampCheck function:

```
timestampCheck(timestamp) {
  var int_max = 65536;
  this.base = 0;
  var diff = "";
  var start = parseInt(this.contatore);
  for (let i = 0; i < timestamp.length; i++) {
    let timestamp = parseInt(timestamp[i]);
    diff = (this.base + timestamp) - start;
    if (diffDestro < 0) {
      this.base+= int_max;
      diff += this.base;
    }
    this.tempoReale.push(diff);
  }
}
```

This function is called from the two function `stopClick` and `write` and there I have a variable `this.base`. Now I don't want that this variable loose his value when it leaves the functions `timestampCheck`. For example the arrayTimestamp has a size > 1000 an so it call the write() functions. here calculations are made and the value of this.base is set.

At this point, if the user clicks the stop key, the stopClick () function is called which calls the same timestampCheck function and must resume the previous value of this.base and not start from scratch.

How do you think I can do it?

thank you so much.

Comment: I guess you just need to stop setting `this.base` to 0 at the beginning of the function, initialize it outside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a variable outside of the function to store the new value.

So outside of the function:

```
    var countingValue = 0;

    function timestampCheck(timestamp) {
 
        var int_max = 65536;

        this.base = 0;

        var valueToUse = countingValue > 0 ? countingValue : this.base;

        var diff = 0;

        var start = parseInt(this.contatore);

        for (let i = 0; i < timestamp.length; i++) {

          let timestamp = parseInt(timestamp[i]);

          diff = (valueToUse + timestamp) - start;

          if (diffDestro < 0) {
            valueToUse += int_max;
            diff += valueToUse;
          }

          this.tempoReale.push(diff);

          countingValue = countingValue + diff;
        }
    }
```

So what I have done here is create a variable outside of the function named **countingValue** with an initial value of 0.

Then underneath the initialisation of **this.base** I have used a type of **If** statement known as a **ternary operator** which says if the current **countingValue** is more than 0 then we will store that value in a variable named **valueToUse** otherwise we will use the **this.base** value and store it in the **valueToUse** variable.

In the rest of the code I have used the **valueToUse** variable for the computations now instead of **this.base**.

Note: I changed your variable **diff** to an integer because it was a string. You may want to review this and swap a couple of variables around if it's not exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And in this way i Save the value and i can use it when It Is called from the two functions??

Comment: Check my updated answer, at the bottom of my answer. It should work how you intend it to work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) But why when I try to declare a variable outside the function it returns me an error?

Comment: Can I ask a question about it?
You said to do at the end this: `countingValue = countingValue + diff;`
But why did you incrrement countingValue at every circle?

Comment: Because For example if I have: `valueToUse = 0`, `timestamp = 40` and `contatore=20`. I have `diff = 20` so my `countingValue = 20`. but in the next loop `valueToUse` turns out to be equal to 0 (this.base) and not as the `countingValue`